# MySQL: Another max per group? Two tables

Tags: mysql

My database tracks sections users have completed:

Table 'users':

```
id    user_id    sections_id
//
 4         46              1
 5         46              2
 6         46              4
 7         46              5
//
```

Table 'sections':

```
id    header_id    name
 1            1     1/3
 2            1     2/3
 3            1     3/3
 4            2     1/3
 5            2     2/3
 6            2     3/3
```

The following query

```
SELECT a.sections_id
      ,b.header_id
FROM users a
JOIN sections b
ON a.sections_id = b.id
WHERE a.user_id = 46;
// a.user_id can be just user_id, but added for clarity
```

Gives me:

```
sections_id    header_id
          1            1
          2            1
          4            2
          5            2
```

What I want is max section ID per header for a particular user, so that I know which section I need to serve the user:

```
sections_id    header_id
          2            1
          5            2
```

I'm assuming this is a max per group problem, but I can't quite get my head around the solution. I could throw all the data into my PHP and parse out from there, but it seems I should be able to do it via the SQL. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `group by` query:

```
SELECT s.header_id, max(u.sections_id)
FROM users u JOIN
     sections s
     ON u.sections_id = s.id
WHERE u.user_id = 46
group by s.header_id;
```

I also changed your aliases to be the initials of the table.  This makes the query much easier to follow.

Edit: SQLFiddle Here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbb5a/2

Answer (score 1):

You could add a group by clause with a max() function

```
SELECT max(a.sections_id)
      ,b.header_id
FROM users a
JOIN sections b
ON a.sections_id = b.id
WHERE a.user_id = 46
GROUP BY header_id;
```